# Autohotkey: how to declare global variable after #ifwinactive

Tags: if-statement, variables, global-variables, autohotkey, declare

When I declare a global variable after #ifwinactive, an error message pop up showing that the variable is not declared.

I have a long script where there are many #ifwinactive ahk_exe xxx. Below those codes, I want to declare a global variable. But that doesn't work. Whenever I run the script, it warns me the global variable is not declared. Here's a brief of my script.

On the top of the script I have these environment settings:

```
#NoEnv  
#Warn  
SendMode Input 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
```

Then I have many window-specific hotkeys:

```
#ifwinactive ahk_exe Explorer.EXE
;some hotkeys
#ifwinactive ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE
;some extra hotkeys
;etc.
```

At the bottom, I try to declare a global variable and this is where the error occurs:

```
#ifwinactive
a := 1
^p::
    if (a != 1){
        a := 1
    } else {
        a := 0
    }
return 

#if winactive("- YouTube -") and a != 1
    p::msgbox,Yes
#if a = 1 and winactive("- YouTube -")
    p::msgbox,no
#if
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're declaring the variable `a` outside of the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).
Code execution never actually reaches `a := 1`, it's stopped when your first hotkey definition is met.
Also, it's not an error, just a warning. Due to how forgiving AHK is, it doesn't actually matter if you don't declare the variable before use. It'll start off with the default value of *nothing*, which works for your `a != 1` check.
Also, after you run the `^p` hotkey at least once, it'll behave as intended.

But anyway, to get rid of warning, you'd declare the variable in the auto-execute section of your script (at the top).

And an extra thing to consider:
Don't use [`#If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#General_Remarks) unless you actually need it. It can cause trouble (as the documentation states), depending on what sort of a script you have.
If a win active check, and a toggle is all you need to check for, I don't think it really warrants usage of `#If`.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more on your last point? Yes, what I want to do is to create a hotkey to toggle other hotkeys' functionality within an app.

Comment: `#if` is good for a condition you really need check before the hotkey fires, but sounds like you don't need that. Instead you could do something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/w13gQMf.png).

Comment: It seems that `if()` works better for a single hotkey, while `#if` works better for more than one hotkeys like [this](https://imgur.com/a/9Qt3JvY).

Comment: Yes, that is most definitely very convenient and in a simple script like that it's more than likely going to be just fine. Just remember that if you ever run into the trouble `#if` can bring, you can ditch it.